# Can I store more than one file with overwriting the other files in the same folder in python having the same name

Tags: python-3.8

I have a dictionary file that has the following structure,if I have some files with the existing data.json name already,how can I store the more files to the same directory without overwriting the data.json file

```
myRecord= {
 'name':'ivan',
 'age':'19'
}

j = json.dumps(myRecord)

with open('data.json','a') as f:
f.write(j)
```

Comment: without knowing any more context that this,  the obvious thing to do would be save them with a different filename.

Comment: So every time I modify the file, I have to save it with a different name